# Why goes a layout root through an observer?

Tags: java, android

For some hours I have been working at my new Android App, but tangle up myself at a very strange Exception.
Means the Exception is clear, but i do not understand the content behind it.

I have an activity named MainActivity like this :

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements Observer {

```
 private gameState st = new gameState();
 private gameEngine bc;
 public RelativeLayout gameLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    st.addObserver(this);
    gameLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.gLayout);
    startGame();

}


@Override
public void update(Observable observable, Object data) {

    int gameState = ((gameState) observable).getState();

    if(gameState == 1){
        continueGame();
    }

    if(gameState == 2){
        killGame();
    }
}

private void killGame(){

    if(!bc.BarThread.isInterrupted()){
    bc.BarThread.interrupt();
    }
    gameLayout.removeAllViewsInLayout();

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            );
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);

    gameLayout.addView(tv, params);
    tv.setText("Game Over");
}
```

}

My simple gameState class:

```
public class gameState extends Observable{

private int state = 0;

public gameState() {

}

public void setState(int var){

    synchronized(this){
        state = var;
    }
    setChanged();
    notifyObservers();

}

public synchronized int getState(){

    return state;

}
```

}

And my gameEngine (instantiated as bc), which is too long, to post here, but i can try to explain the content in easy words.

The Game Engine features some game Elements like Buttons and an ProgressBar and a Thread (BarThread) which fills the Bar continuously.
if the user is successful, the gameEngine sets the gameState to 1 and the MainActivity does something like the killGame() Method, which works perfectly.

If the user is too slow and the ProgressBar is full, the BarThread sets the gameState to two.
Then MainActivity does killGame and throws

```
 android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

But I can not understand why the Thread has an effect throught the observer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing `BarThread` calls `setState(int var)`, right? If that's true, then that method is called on a thread that is NOT the main thread. That means that everything that `setState()` calls (e.g. `notifyObservers()`) is not called on the main thread. I'm guessing that `notifyObservers()` eventually calls `MainActivity.update(Observable observable, Object data)`, which calls `killGame()`, which changes the view hierarchy (i.e. adding a text view). This means that your view hierarchy is modified from a thread that is not the main thread.

You're probably going to need to create a `Handler` in `MainActivity`. Then in `killGame()`, call `Handler.post(Runnable runnable)`. Something like this:

```
private Handler handler;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  handler = new Handler();
}

private void killGame() {
  if(!bc.BarThread.isInterrupted()){
    bc.BarThread.interrupt();
  }

  handler.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      gameLayout.removeAllViewsInLayout();

      RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
      );
      TextView tv = new TextView(MainActivity.this);

      gameLayout.addView(tv, params);
      tv.setText("Game Over");
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: your answer looks quite good, but how can I set the Context of the TextView, because 'this' is now Runnable and not MainActivity ?

Comment: You should be able to use `MainActivity.this`. Another option is to create the TextView outside of the `handler.post()` call. You'll need to make it `final`, but then you should be able to simply call the last 2 lines (`addView()` and `setText()`) in `handler.post()`